# Read cookie in CanActivate route guard in Angular

Tags: angular, angular9

I am using Angular 9 and the [CanAngular](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface to protect a route being called when the user is not logged in. During login I set a cookie `session_key`, but I don't know how I can read/get the cookie value again in the `canActivate` function of the interface.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private accountService: AccountService
    ) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
            if (cookieExists("session_key")) {  <---------------------- 
                // authorised so return true
                return true;
            }

            // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
            this.router.navigate(['/account/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
            return false;
    }
}
```

What existing function would I use for `cookieExists`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **ngx-cookie-service** you need to import the Cookie Service in authguard.

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
```

and in constructor inject the cookie service

```
constructor(private cookieService : CookieService){}
```

Then you can use the below code to access the cookie storage

```
if (cookieService.get("session_key")) { 
   return true;
}
```

You can set the cookie using below code

```
cookieService.set('session-key','some-value');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple utility function to check for it:

```
export function cookieExists(cookie: string): boolean { 
  return document.cookie
    .split(';')
    .some((item) => item.trim().startsWith(`${cookie}=`)));
}
```

And use this in your `canActivate`:

```
canActivate(): boolean | UrlTree {
  if (cookieExists('session_key')) {
    return true;
  }

  return this.router.createUrlTree(
    ['/account/login'],
    { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }}
  );
}
```

The proper way to redirect from a guard is by returning a [`UrlTree`](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlTree)